# Simulation of MOSFETs as high-speed switches

Tags: mosfet, analog, spice, analog-switch

I’m trying to simulate high-speed switches (2xSPDT) made of MOSFETs.

The MOSFETs should switch so that while “I2” flows into output, “I1” flows into “U_1” (or vice versa).

I couldn’t interpret the behaviour of the currents flowing into the output. Did I cause an error somewhere in the circuit? Did I make a mistake when setting up the circuit?

Here is the circuit.
[image: Circuit 1]

And here is the result of the simulation.
[image: Simulation1]

I add diode//Res to the gates according to advice of Tony Stewart EE75.
Now the circuit looks like:
[image: Circuit 2]

And the result of that looks like:
[image: Simulation 2]

But the behaviour of the currents seems to not be ok. I need your help.

Comment: `“I1” flows into “U_1”` - where's U_1? `I couldn’t interpret the behaviour of the currents flowing into the output.` - what was the problem that prevented you doing so? Where's the `output`?

Comment: @Andyaka you can see those labels on the circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spikes in Id show a clear lack of deadband in the crossover timing.  Correct that with suitable 1us +/-50% delays with asymmetric rise times to gate or inputs using a diode // R.  (I.e fast turn off, slow turn on)

- consult App notes for details.

Comment: I add diode//R to gates. You can see the result above.

Comment: a few mA current is normal to charge up the Miller Capacitance,  Coss.   deadtime is too big now., I forgot how much shootthru you had before, maybe that was low enough for room temp.  Nothing unusual to report otherwise